# Component Child is not re-rendered although state updated

Tags: reactjs

I did not use reducer for this case to update state change on component. I send prop to child Component and I want it will be updated every time state changed on parent Component.

In the mother Component, I set state currentPage by default is 1;

```
const [pager, setPager] = useState({
    currentPage: 1
  });

const propToSend = pager.currentPage;

//and make trigger change:
const onClick = (e) => {
 setPager({...pager, currentPage:5});
}
....return...
<Pagination pageProp={propToSend} />
```

in Pagination Component I got state and set it into new State:

```
const Pagination = (props) => {
  const currentPage = props.pageProp
  const [pager, setPager] = useState({
    currentPage
  });

 const changeActivePage(num)=> {
   setPager({..pager, currentPage:num});
 }
  .....
 const paginomal = ListPagers.map(num => (
    <li key="num" onClick={changeActivePage(num)}>{num}</li>
 ));
  return(
    <Fragment>
      {paginomal}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

If you can see if I make change pager on mother Compoment  with function

```
//and make trigger change:
const onClick = (e) => {
 setPager({...pager, currentPage:5});
}
```

Then nothing happen on pager.

Can you tell me how to trigger to change from mother Component because state is changed with click event on Child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your pagination state when the currentPage from props updates. Using an effect hook can accomplish this. The `useEffect` hook triggers once for the first mount of the component, then again each time a value in its dependency array (the second argument) is changed. In this case, when the `currentPage` value is changed from, say, 1 to 2.

```
const Pagination = (props) => {
  const currentPage = props.pageProp;

  const [pager, setPager] = useState({
    currentPage
  });

  useEffect(() => setPager(currentPage), [currentPage]);

  const changeActivePage(num)=> {
    setPager({..pager, currentPage:num});
  }
  .....
  const paginomal = ListPagers.map(num => (
    <li key="num" onClick={changeActivePage(num)}>{num}</li>
  ));
  return(
    <Fragment>
      {paginomal}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

**But now you've two sources of truth!!** And it can be difficult to keep them in sync, hence the above issue you had. It may be better to instead pass the `setPager` function from the "mother" to the child as a callback. It then updates the state stored in the parent component, the single source of truth.

```
const Pagination = ({ pageProp, onPageChange }) => {
  const currentPage = pageProp;

  const changeActivePage(num)=> {
    onPageChange({ currentPage: num });
  }
  .....
  const paginomal = ListPagers.map(num => (
    <li key="num" onClick={changeActivePage(num)}>{num}</li>
  ));
  return(
    <Fragment>
      {paginomal}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Then from Mother

```
const [pager, setPager] = useState({
    currentPage: 1
  });

const propToSend = pager.currentPage;

//and make trigger change:
const onClick = (e) => {
  setPager({...pager, currentPage:5});
}
....return...
<Pagination pageProp={propToSend} onPageChange={setPager} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain about your useEffect?

Comment: @HaiTien Updated answer with a bit more explanation about the effect.

Comment: I think the second solution of yours is easy to handle. I m trying on this

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I learn new way to send prop with multiple changes on state of app. It is so awesome.

Comment: I marked your answer is best. Thank you so much. I knew new way from yours instead of calling reducer.

Comment: Can you see my latest question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720114/how-to-render-data-from-redux-store-while-action-and-reducer-called-in-the-same

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to keep a separate state in your child component then you should pass you `onClick` method as **props** to your child component and then use it something like below

```
const paginomal = ListPagers.map(num => (
    <li key="num" onClick={() => onClick(num)}>{num}</li>
  ));
```

And in your parent component you can write something like

```
//and make trigger change:
const onClick = (num) => {
 setPager({...pager, currentPage:num});
}
....return...
<Pagination pageProp={propToSend} onClick={onClick}/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it after Drew Reese method.

Comment: Yeah sure it is up to you to choose an approach but remember to keep your code simpler and clean as much as possible.